# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined to recive params from url node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send url a date taken from a html table, which has a button where I send by POST the url with action `'/item/2016-04-04'` but it comes out in the

> Uncaught browser ReferenceError: $ is not Defined   At 2016-01-01: 1;
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found).

client side:

```
<form role="form" action="/item/2016-01-01" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Ver</button></form>
```

server side:

```
app.post('/item/:date', function(req, res){
  if(!req.carPoolSession.username){
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    db_handler.obtener_localizacion_departamento_local(req.carPoolSession.username,function(queryResLocalDepLocalizacion){
      console.log(req.params.id);
      res.render('vista_caja_chica_item.jade',{username:req.carPoolSession.username,titulo:queryResLocalDepLocalizacion});
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post this result `else { console.log(req);`....just to check if the request reach that piece of code....

Comment: Are you using jQuery on the client-side?

Comment: is your JQuery script loaded correctly?

Comment: yes in all the pages is loaded correctly but when i tried in that url the page closed the server